# Get AccessToken to GetList In Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure-ad, azure-ad-graph-api, postman

I used sharepoint office 365 and I tried to get list item from sharepoint through postman.

I follow the steps in these links:

https://medium.com/@anoopt/accessing-sharepoint-data-using-postman-sharepoint-rest-api-76b70630bcbf

http://www.ktskumar.com/2017/01/access-sharepoint-online-using-postman/

but did not work, I got response Access denied and sometimes 403 Forbidden.

and I tried to registration app & graph API in azure but I got same result.

I wanna clear way to get right access token.

and another question what can I put in Redirect URI ? https://localhost or my main link page

thanks